# JSF, Primefaces - 'Cannot format given Object as a Date' in case of an instructor call

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm very to to jsf and Primefaces. My problem is, if I do not comment `currentLunch = new Lunch(...)`in *IndexBean.java` out, I'll get the error message which I've append below.

Without this line of code, the code will run.

**Why I do that?**

I want to add a new lunch instance in case of a 'save' click. That's why the 'add'-form has an empty instance of a lunch object. Is this way okay?

I checked the following Stackoverflow posts but I think, their solution would not solve my problem

- [JSF Cannot format given Object as a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151700/jsf-cannot-format-given-object-as-a-date)
- [Java : Cannot format given Object as a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649782/java-cannot-format-given-object-as-a-date)

**Error log**

`1100: JSF1073: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Cannot format given Object as a Date`

**Code**

*Index.htmlx*

```
<h:form id="newLunch">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 300px;">
            <h:outputLabel for="initiator" value="Initiator" />
            <p:inputText id="initiator" value="#{indexBean.currentLunch.initiator}"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="date" value="Date" />
            <p:calendar id="date" minHour="11" maxHour="13" stepMinute="15" value="#{indexBean.currentLunch.date}"/>

            <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{indexBean.onSaveLunch}" update=":lunches" />
        </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

*IndexBean.java*

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean
{
private List<Lunch> lunches;
private Lunch currentLunch;
public List<Lunch> getLunches() ...
public void setLunches(List<Lunch> lunches) ...
public Lunch getCurrentLunch() ...
public void setCurrentLunch(Lunch currentLunch) ...

public IndexBean()
{
    // Set attributes to a value whichs should work (as you can see one line below)
    currentLunch = new Lunch("Tobi", "Starbucks", new DateTime(2014, 5, 30, 12, 0, 0 ,0));

    // This works without any problems.
    lunches = new ArrayList<Lunch>();
    lunches.add(new Lunch("Tobi", "Starbucks", new DateTime(2014, 5, 30, 12, 0, 0 ,0)));
}

public void onSaveLunch() ...
```

}

*Lunch.java*

```
public class Lunch
{
    private String initiator;
    private String location;
    private DateTime date;

    public Lunch(String initiator, String location, DateTime date)
    {
        this.initiator = initiator != null ? initiator : "";
        this.location = location != null ? location : "";
        this.date = date != null ? date : DateTime.now();
    }

    // default getter / setter


    public String getFormattedDate()
    {
        if(date == null) return "";
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:MM (dd.MM.yyyy)");
        return date.toString(fmt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arise when you're not using `java.util.Date`. Check that the respective field in `Lunch` class has `java.util.Date` type and not `java.sql.Date` or another type.

Looks like you're using `DateTime` for Joda API. To solve this issue and not modify your current design, you may want to have a custom getter/setter for `date` field in your view. Just add this code to `IndexBean`:

```
public class IndexBean {
    //current code...
    public Date getDate() {
        if (currentLunch.getDate() != null) {
            return currentLunch.getDate().toDate();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        return currentLunch.setDate(new DateTime(date));
    }
}
```

And change the view to:

```html
<!-- Note the expression language in value attribute -->
<p:calendar id="date" minHour="11" maxHour="13" stepMinute="15"
    value="#{indexBean.date}"/>
```

---

Not related to your current problem, but maybe `@SessionScoped` is a wider scope than you will need, probably the bean should be `@ViewScoped`.

Also, it is better to have any business logic associated to the bean initialization in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method:

```
public class IndexBean {
    public IntexBean() {
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Set attributes to a value whichs should work (as you can see one line below)
        currentLunch = new Lunch("Tobi", "Starbucks", new DateTime(2014, 5, 30, 12, 0, 0 ,0));
        // This works without any problems.
        lunches = new ArrayList<Lunch>();
        lunches.add(new Lunch("Tobi", "Starbucks", new DateTime(2014, 5, 30, 12, 0, 0 ,0)));
    }
    //rest of code...
}
```

Comment: Big thanks Luiggi. It's late in Germany and I'll test it tomorrow. In case of success, I'll mark your post as 'the answer'.

Comment: I would suggest steering away from adding logic into your getters/setters, mostly due to potential null pointers on currentLaunch. If you really want to use DateTime on view your view Layer you could add a f:converter and generate a jsf converter than does the logic conversion from Date to DateTime. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641001/convert-jsf-calendar-date-into-jodatime-in-converter where they suggest using just util.Date for View, and DateTime in Business. :)

Comment: @VeenarM if OP already has lot of classes using Joda Time instead of `java.util.Date` then switching may not be an option. If not, then BalusC's suggestion would be great.

Comment: Agreed, in which case creating a converter may be a better option - I would suggest that than putting the conversion in 'all' of your getters/setters yes?

Comment: Thanks to rest for also supporting a newbie!